# Как сгенерировать четырехзначное число без повторов цифр?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, случайные-числа, комбинаторика

Делаю игру, в ней мне нужен "бот" которые будет выдавать мне рандомное число, но оно должно быть , так же в числе не может быть одинаковых цифр. Например, бот выдает 1223, оно не подходит, бот даёт следующее число 3213, оно так же не подходит и так до того момента пока в числе не будет одинаковых цифр, например: 1234.

Мой код работает не очень, вот он:

```
import random
def get_random_number(self):
    random_number = random.randint(0000, 9999)
    if len(str(random_number)) == 4:
        lst_number = list(str(random_number))
        for i in range(0, len(lst_number)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(lst_number)):
                if lst_number[i] == lst_number[j]:
                    random_number = random.randint(0000, 9999)
                    if len(str(random_number)) == 4:
                        lst_number = list(str(random_number))
                        print(random_number, " and ", lst_number)
                        return random_number
```

Comment: В чем выражается "не очень"? Если нужно число четырёхзначное, то надо и начинать с 1023, а не с 0, тогда и длину проверять не потребуется.

Comment: Он не даёт мне нужный результат

Comment: Сказано то же самое, но другими словами 

Comment: Сгенерируйте отдельно 4 однозначных числа, проверьте, что они различны, и составьте четырёхзначное.

Comment: Создавайте буфферный лист в котором запишите все цифры(от 0 до 9). И 4 раза генерируйте рандомное число от 0 до n(кол-во оставшихся в листе цифр). Это рандомное число будет индекс к вашему листу. По индексу - очередная цифра вашего четырехзначного числа. Получили число - удалили его из листа.

Comment: Это если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую)

Answer (score 13):

Без нуля:

```
import random
digits = random.sample("123456789",4)
print(int("".join(digits)))
```

С нулем немного сложнее, потому что тогда нужно проверять, чтобы он не оказался на первой позиции. Например, так:

```
import random
digits = random.sample("1234567890",4) # 4 элемента без повторов из заданной коллекции
number = int("".join(digits)) # соединяем в одно и конвертируем в число
if number < 1000: # если первая цифра была 0...
    number = number * 10 # ...то добавляем его в конец
print(number)
```

Comment: Еще для py38 можно такой вариант использовать `int("".join([x:=choice("123456789")] + sample([c for c in "1234567890" if c != x], 3)))`

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, так короче и однообразнее.  По крайней мере без лишних проверок.

```
from random import sample

digits = list('0123456789')

first_digit = sample(digits[1:], 1)   # список из одной цифры-символа
digits.remove(first_digit[0])
x = "".join(first_digit + sample(digits, 3))
```

про скорость не скажу, но все равно лучше, чем в цикле приклеивать по одному символу.
Здесь первый список состоит из одного символа-цифры, причем предварительно нарезкой отбросили ноль. Второй список - выборка трех неповторяющихся чисел с возможным нулем. Складываем два списка и результирующий список склеиваем.
Добавьте `int()`. Если он нужен.

Используя множества, можно сделать на одну строчку короче:

```
digits = '123456789'
first_digit = sample(digits, 1)   # список из одной цифры-символа
x = "".join(first_digit + sample(list(set(digits) - set(first_digit) | {'0'}), 3))
```